# How to remove the core stylesheets from a theme

Tags: hooks

I am developing a Drupal theme and noticed the following CSS files are added automatically by Drupal. I would like to them to be removed.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/ajax-progress.module.css?owah24" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/align.module.css?owah24" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/autocomplete-loading.module.css?owah24" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/fieldgroup.module.css?owah24" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/container-inline.module.css?owah24" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/clearfix.module.css?owah24" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/details.module.css?owah24" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/hidden.module.css?owah24" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/item-list.module.css?owah24" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/js.module.css?owah24" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/nowrap.module.css?owah24" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/position-container.module.css?owah24" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/progress.module.css?owah24" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/reset-appearance.module.css?owah24" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/resize.module.css?owah24" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/sticky-header.module.css?owah24" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/system-status-counter.css?owah24" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/system-status-report-counters.css?owah24" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/system-status-report-general-info.css?owah24" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/tabledrag.module.css?owah24" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/tablesort.module.css?owah24" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/core/themes/stable/css/system/components/tree-child.module.css?owah24" media="all" />
```

I have tried two ways to remove it. First one is using `libraries-override`

```
libraries-override:
  system/base:
    css:
      component:
        /core/modules/system/css/components/align.module.css: false
```

The next one is using `hook_alter_css`

```
function hook_css_alter(&$css, \Drupal\Core\Asset\AttachedAssetsInterface $assets) {
  unset($css[drupal_get_path('module', 'system') . 'css/components/align.module.css']);
}
```

Comment: On the `libraries-override`, does it work if you take the leading slash out of the path (`/core`) and rebuild the cache?

Comment: @PatrickKenny No luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went to the **stable** theme, checked the `.info.yml` file and `libraries-override` section.

I have removed the stylesheets using the following snippets.

```
libraries-override:
  system/base:
    css:
      component:
        css/components/ajax-progress.module.css: false
        css/components/align.module.css: false
        css/components/autocomplete-loading.module.css: false
        css/components/fieldgroup.module.css: false
        css/components/container-inline.module.css: false
        css/components/clearfix.module.css: false
        css/components/details.module.css: false
        css/components/hidden.module.css: false
        css/components/item-list.module.css: false
        css/components/js.module.css: false
        css/components/nowrap.module.css: false
        css/components/position-container.module.css: false
        css/components/progress.module.css: false
        css/components/reset-appearance.module.css: false
        css/components/resize.module.css: false
        css/components/sticky-header.module.css: false
        css/components/system-status-counter.css: false
        css/components/system-status-report-counters.css: false
        css/components/system-status-report-general-info.css: false
        css/components/tabledrag.module.css: false
        css/components/tablesort.module.css: false
        css/components/tree-child.module.css: false
```

Answer (score 8):

Also, you can **exclude a whole library** at all by adding:

```
libraries-override:
  system/base: false
```

Answer (score 1):

If you override "stable" theme :

```
libraries-override:
  system/base: false
```

is enough...

If you override an other theme as "classy" you have to remove useless css files like that :

```
libraries-override:
system/base:
  css:
    component:
      css/components/ajax-progress.module.css: false
      css/components/align.module.css: false
      css/components/autocomplete-loading.module.css: false
      ...
```