# libraries-override not working

Tags: theming, 8

I'm trying to figure out how I can remove the default css libraries of Drupal 8 on the theme I'm working on. I tried using `libraries-override:` to remove a specific `CSS` but it doesn't seem to be working. The css file is still showing. As you can see the align.module.css is still showing on Google Network Tab. I'm not sure if the method I'm using is deprecated or incorrect

[image]

```
name: Barebones
description: Drupal light
type: theme
core: 8.x

base theme: stable

libraries-override:
  system/base:
    css:
      component:
        /core/modules/system/css/components/align.module.css: false
```

[image]

```
libraries-override:
  system/base: false
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override a library using the filename as key.

```
libraries-override:
  system/base:
    css:
      component:
        css/components/align.module.css: false
```

But if your asset was already overwritten by another module (e.g. classy theme overriding a core system asset), you have to use the full path instead, example:

```
libraries-override:
  system/base:
    css:
      component:
        /core/themes/stable/css/system/components/ajax-progress.module.css: false
```

Also see [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2642122#comment-10705712).

Comment: Tried your solution but it didn't work. Saw a similar question with a correct answer. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/246796/how-to-remove-the-core-stylesheets-from-drupal-8-theme Tried doing the same solution but didn't work

Comment: Did you clear the cache? e.g. `drush cr`

Comment: Yes I did, /admin/config/development/performance. Even tried rebuild.php

Comment: Sorry, was wrong with the path comment, found [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2642122#comment-10705712): when your library is already overwritten, the key gets replaced with a drupal-root relative path, so your intial syntax should be correct. Enter the full path, starting with the drupal root.

Comment: Not sure what happened but I managed to remove or lessen the number of default drupal css being loading using the following code `libraries-override:
  system/base: false` There are still a number of css being loaded is there a way to remove them. See 2nd screenshot

Comment: The code in your initial question disables a single file of a library, the code in your last comment disables the entire library (all js and css files). Every active module in Drupal can define and add libraries, so you'll end up with a lot of CSS files (but they are usually needed for the functionality of that module, so don't disable them en gros)

Comment: Is there a way to omit all of the default JS and CSS of drupal 8. I'm currently trying to create a lighter version of drupal as an experiment

Comment: Simple answer: no. If you want a lighter Drupal, disable some modules. By concept Drupal's frontend and backend are not fully separated, what you are trying to do will not work.

Comment: I edited your answer to remove the path suggestion which you acknowledged in your comments was incorrect.

Comment: Glen, I've updated the answer, using both examples. Just removing that comment wouldn't help people wondering when to use the relative path and when the absolute path.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood; [the documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-theme#override-extend) shows to use the full path to the file you want to override. I thought your (comment, not answer) was acknowledging the error in your answer. Are you saying that an optional syntax is to refer to a css file in your own theme to override a css file found in the parent theme?